# Opening a new terminal in vscode for 'start' command in .bat files

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-code

I have a **run.bat** file with the following commands:

```
start emulator.bat
react-native run-android
```

I'm running my **run.bat** in vscode terminal.
The 'start' command opens a new command line outside of vscode.

What I want is for that command to open a new terminal in vscode.
How can I do that?

**Update:**

The reason I used `start emulator.bat` is because emulator's output looks like this (the command doesn't end):

[image]

Comment: Why not just `call emulator.bat`?

Comment: Because this command doesn't end. If I write something after this line it wont run it.

Comment: Yes it will. If you just wrote `emulator.bat` then the rest of `run.bat` would not run. But writing `call emulator.bat` means it will call the other batch file and when that finishes it will return to `run.bat` to execute the remaining lines.

Comment: See my update in the question please.

Comment: I see now. I'm not sure it can be done, but maybe someone who knows VS Code well can tell us.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to delete the `start` command from your file.
**your updated code:**

```
emulator.bat
react-native run-android
```